# SQL query to search multiple values from same column

Tags: sql, ms-access

My table has field like `empID` and `Skills`, where one `empID` can have several `Skills` entered in different rows.

```
empID    skill
G001     ASP.NET
G002     VB
G003     SQL Server
G001     C#
G002     Crystal report
```

Now I want to search on multiple skills, like which id have `skills = ASP.NET and C#`.

I am using `MS access` as backend and `Visual basic 6` as frontend.

Please provide me SQL query.

Comment: Please give it a try first.

Answer (score 0):

You could do like below:

```
SELECT empID
FROM your_table
WHERE skill IN ('ASP.NET', 'C#')
GROUP BY empID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT skill) >= 2 # use = if you want exactly that 2 skills
```